# Can we add a login module whose slot is different from main to a global valve in jboss eap 6.4?

Tags: java, security, jboss6.x

I want to add a login module whose slot="20" to a global valve in jboss eap 6.4 like the following:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">    
    <valve name="myvalve" module="com.xxxx.inf.jaas-oauth:20" class-name="com.xxxx.inf.security.jaas.valve.GatewayProofAuthenticatorValve"/>
</subsystem>
```

this module has been added to my security domain also like the follwoing:

```
<security-domain name="Member" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="com.xxxx.inf.security.jaas.loginmodule.UsaaMemberGatewayProofLoginModuleJboss" flag="required" module="com.xxxx.inf.jaas-oauth:20"/>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

The slot 20 works for login module but not when I add it to global valve. Not sure if I am configuring it in a wrong way or I cannot configure global valve with a login module whose slot is different from main. Please suggest.